# mr-md-5 is not working for me in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

Please identify my fault

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 mr-md-5 bg-success">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam, dicta corporis iusto ea reiciendis suscipit alias odit adipisci esse beatae at tempore ullam accusantium atque recusandae molestias voluptatem obcaecati modi.</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 mt-md-4 bg-warning">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, at.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 dropped `mr-` and `ml-` for `me-` and `ms-` respectively:

> Breaking - Renamed several utilities to use logical property names
> instead of directional names with the addition of RTL support:
> Renamed .ml-* and .mr-* to .ms-* and .me-*.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#utilities